# How to get Facebook user id during deauthorization

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using new Facebook C# SDK 5.0.2, and I encountered the following problem:
During application deuthorization I have value of singed_request. Unfortunatelly they doesn't have accesstoken so If I'm using CanvasAuthorizer and the Session is null, so I don't known which user should I mark as disabled in my application.

Is there any workaround for this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the signed request using... FacebookSignedRequest.Parse

```
string signedRequestValue = Request.Form["signed_request"];
var app = new FacebookApp();
var sig = FacebookSignedRequest.Parse(((FacebookConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("facebookSettings")).AppSecret, signedRequestValue);
long userid = long.Parse(sig.UserId);
```